# How to vertically center Bootstrap columns that are inside another column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to vertically center the divs inside `col-md-12`. This is the structure:

```css
.list-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.list-item img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.col-md-2 {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-item col-md-12 clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <img class="img-circle" src="https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/_skies/puydesancy.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <strong>
      <a href="#/buildings/1">Central park</a>
    </strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <span>The description for central park description for the central park</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <span>Category count:</span>
    <strong>3</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <span>Panorama count:</span>
    <strong>7</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried: `vertical-align: middle` and `display: inline` but it didn't work. Is there another way?

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wLgfLo3L/

(You need to resize the browser to full screen).

Comment: which div you need to be vertically centered?

Comment: @satya the divs inside `col-md-12`.

Comment: That construct is invalid, a col must be within a row and a row within a container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple solution for this is with this css.

**HMTL**

```
<div class="list-item col-md-12 clearfix main">
  <div class="col-md-1 center">
    <img class="img-circle" src="https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/_skies/puydesancy.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center">
    <strong>
      <a href="#/buildings/1">Central park</a>
    </strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 center">
    <span>The description for central park description for the central park</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center">
    <span>Category count:</span>
    <strong>3</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 center">
    <span>Panorama count:</span>
    <strong>7</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main{
  display:table;
}
.center{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

In the above codes i have added `.main` class to main div and `.center` class to div you want to align center.

With `display:table` to main and `display:table-cell` to inner div you can center align the div with `vertical-align:middle` because this converts the nature of div to table.

Here is the updated fiddle link check it https://jsfiddle.net/yudi/wLgfLo3L/1/

Comment: Here's a fiddle with all the elements given a different background color https://jsfiddle.net/f6bu0tnk/1/